# When I try download image i got 403

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I try download image from this url with node: http://blueraven.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/03-4.jpg , but instead image data I got 403 html page. Why ? I can access image without problem with browser or postman. This is my node code:

```
var http = require('http');

var imageData = '';

http.get('http://blueraven.pl/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/03-4.jpg', function (resp) {
    resp.on('data', function(chunk){
        imageData += chunk;
    });

    resp.on('end', function(){
        console.log("Im here hehe :)");
        console.log(imageData);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the permissions to access that file directory and it's files.

for full info look here : http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E403.html

HTTP Error 403 Forbidden

Introduction
The Web server (running the Web site) thinks that the HTTP data stream sent by the client (e.g. your Web browser or our CheckUpDown robot) was correct, but access to the resource identified by the URL is forbidden for some reason.

This indicates a fundamental access problem, which may be difficult to resolve because the HTTP protocol allows the Web server to give this response without providing any reason at all. So the 403 error is equivalent to a blanket 'NO' by the Web server - with no further discussion allowed.

By far the most common reason for this error is that directory browsing is forbidden for the Web site. Most Web sites want you to navigate using the URLs in the Web pages for that site. They do not often allow you to browse the file directory structure of the site. For example try the following URL (then hit the 'Back' button in your browser to return to this page):

Comment: Did you copy your explanation from somewhere? If yes, at least cite the source.

Answer (score 0):

As details for 403 error suggests:

> The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.

It is mostly because source site has restricted access for cross-domain sites. So if it is your site you need to allow other sites to access the resources.

Comment: This isn't the problem. We all can access the image, it's not forbidden. The problem is probably because of something else...

Comment: No, this is not my site.